# How to initialize a fragment from activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Main Menu and created a `fragment` and its layout.
Now I can't seems to start `fragment` when user presses a button on main menu.
main menu has its own layout.
now is there anyway i could initialize it from a `button`?

```
Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, ExercisesFragment.class));

        }
    });
}
```

I tried it by this but it gives error saying

```
Fragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33811237/4874146

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add fragments using fragment manager:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExercisesFragment fragment = new ExercisesFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

read more on fragments, start here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: okay thanks really appreciated and i currently have only one fragment, so what should be (R.id.??)

Comment: This is a FrameLayout from your activity xml file, ie.: `            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

Comment: Error:(29, 36) error: no suitable method found for add(int,ExercisesFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ExercisesFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)

Comment: @Anders change `add` to `replace`, I have fixed my answer. Also if you are using support library then use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`

Comment: @Anders this `ExercisesFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)` indicates that `ExercisesFragment` does not extends `Fragment` - you know You should extend a Fragment to have a Fragment - right?

Comment: I have extended it already like this public class ExercisesFragment extends Fragment {

Comment: Ok, this might be caused then by the use of getFragmentManager instead of getSupportFragmentManager. Support library puts Fragment in different package.

Answer (score 2):

```
  FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main_fragment, your_fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack("ifneeded");
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: Simple, easy and best solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong! **Intents** are not used to load a fragment.
Solution is to use **[fragment transactions](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)**
to dynamically load the fragment you wish to bring into focus.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Have a **container for the fragment** inside the layout of you activity
   Example: Assuming the layout resource of my activity is `activity_main.xml`, I would have a container **[like so](https://gist.github.com/chi6rag/efd4c6bdc503a459ab55)**
2. Follow **[this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)** guide to create a Fragment
3. Assuming you already have a fragment setup with name `AbcFragment`, use fragment transactions to load the fragment into the container that you just created, whenever the user clicks on the button:

```
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment-container, new AbcFragment)
                .commit();
        }

    });
```

Comment: it says '(' or '[' expected at  .replace(R.id.fragment-container, new  ExercisesFragment) in the end here